# How to handle Server timeout in Expressjs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

I'm facing a weird behaviour when request took more time from the server timeout time. when the server got timeout it executed the API callback function again. So the same function runs multiple times when there is a timeout.

Here is the code example

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
  console.log("API function called");
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
  res.send('success');
  } catch (err) {
    res.send('Error');
  }
});
const PORT = 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
server.timeout = 7000;
```

In the above example the console output is and on browser i am getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
`API function called`
`API function called`

So it is calling the request callback 2 times one when we hit the API and second after 7 seconds when timeout occurs.

Could anyone help me with this how can we catch the timeout error and send a proper response to the user and stop calling the function again.

Comment: it's coz of `server.timeout = 7000`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 requests because you are setting timeout of `7000` and your promise is `10000`. So, your server is trying to resolve the promise.

To resolve the issue, you have to increase your server timeout above your promise.

You can read about how other people handle timeout [here](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/scaling-nodejs/nodejs-timeouts/) and promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: I have set server.timeout = 0; then also it is timeout after 5 min as my request is taking more than 5 min?